# Is there a way to make the Fasttext Wikipedia Model for English Less Spelling Dependent?

Tags: fasttext

I'm trying to do a comparison between the English and Mandarin Wikipedia vectors trained using Fasttext, but I'm encountering the issue that the English Vectors seems to give me a lot of orthographic data but not much semantic data. E.G. Querying nearest neighbors of 'England" gets me orthographically similar non-words such as 'ringland' and 'ingland' as well as my input word followed by punctuation such as "England,". The mandarin vectors do not have this issue and broadly seem to perform better semantically, which I can only assume is due to the lack of spelling information. Is there perhaps a way I can restrict my queries in the English vectors to return only real words so I can stop getting misspellings and punctuation differences back?

Comment: Are you using a specific set of pre-trained vectors, and can you add to your question an example operation (with the code/library that performed it) that's returning unwanted words? As far as I know, any words returned from a Fastttext model were necessarily in the training data, and often people who choose Fasttext (rather than a more-simple word2vec model) want such fuzzy matches. (While I don't know what 'ringland' might be, there's a fair chance that any training contexts that used 'ingland' were typos/misspellings by people who meant 'england'.)

Comment: Also, if you're getting words connected with punctuation, like `'England,'`, that indicates such words were included in the training texts. If you've chosen an off-the-shelf set of pretrained-vectors, you might want to select another that did a better job separating words from commas – or train yourself where you have full control. Or, if you've trained the model yourself, you may want to re-train with improved tokenization.

Comment: Ahh, if that's the case I should probably just use a different model that doesn't have subword data. Thanks!

Comment: Even *with* the subword data, the mdoel will only report actual full-words it knows. So it's likely a bigger factor that (1) the model has *so* many words; & (2) your specific goals better served by only more-prominent hits. Depending on the library, & how your model was created (pretrained or manually-trained), you might be able to limit either training, or neighbor-results, to only more-popular words – & that might help your issues. But without knowing the library & source-of-model (& ideally concrete examples of your failure-cases), whether & how that could be done can't be described.